# Simple_form with devise sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple_form with devise, and I'm having a problem with the form submissions. If a user don't give email id and password while sign in then I have to display error message to user like "Email can't be blank" but it won't show any error messages it will remain on same sign in page with no errors. What can I do? I am using devise version "3.5.6" and simple_form version "3.2.1".

Comment: Please post the form code of devise form.

Comment: = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, method: 'post', url:session_path(resource_name) ,defaults: { input_html: { :class => "form-control" } }) do |f|                                                                             .form-inputs 
= f.input :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email', label: false, required: true, error: "Email can't be blank"
= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Password', label: false, required: true,error: "Password can't be blank"                         .form-actions%button#submitSignIn.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} SignIn

Answer (score 0):

This is my devise code with simple_form

```
.panel-body  
            = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, method: 'post', url:session_path(resource_name) ,defaults: { input_html: { :class => "form-control" } }) do |f|
              .form-inputs 
                - flash.each do |name, msg|
                  = content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String)

                = f.input :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email', label: false, required: true, error: "Email can't be blank"
                = f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Password', label: false, required: true,error: "Password can't be blank"
              .form-actions
                %button#submitSignIn.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} Sign In
                %br
                = render "devise/shared/links"
```